# Update after Trigger

Tags: triggers, updates, hsqldb

I have this trigger running in before insert sentences:

```
CREATE TRIGGER controlHoras before
insert ON conducen 
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow for each row
BEGIN Atomic
declare entrega timestamp;
declare hoy date;
declare horaUsuario timestamp;
declare horaActual timestamp;
set (entrega)= (select max(horaentrega) from conducen where matricula = newrow.matricula and FECHARECOGIDA = newrow.fecharecogida);
set (hoy)= (today);
set (horaUsuario)=(select max(horaentrega) from conducen where FECHARECOGIDA = newrow.fecharecogida and userwin =newrow.userwin);
set (horaActual) = (sysdate);
if(newrow.horaRecogida < entrega) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'El coche esta ocupado a la hora que lo pretendes recoger, elige otra hora u otro coche.';
end if;
if(newrow.fecharecogida<hoy or newrow.HORARECOGIDA<horaActual) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fecha o hora de recogida menor que la fecha actual.';
end if;
if(newrow.horaRecogida<horaUsuario) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No puedes conducir dos coches a la vez.';
end if;
end;
```

But I need control the update setences, I have this trigger but not run correct:

```
CREATE TRIGGER controlHoras1 AFTER
UPDATE ON conducen
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
declare entrega timestamp;
declare hoy date;
declare horaUsuario timestamp;
declare horaActual timestamp;

set (hoy)= (today);
set (horaUsuario)=(select max(oldrow.horaentrega) from conducen where FECHARECOGIDA = newrow.fecharecogida and userwin = newrow.userwin);
set (horaActual) = (sysdate);

if(newrow.fecharecogida < hoy or newrow.HORARECOGIDA < horaActual) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fecha o hora de recogida menor que la fecha actual.';
end if;
if(newrow.horaRecogida < horaUsuario) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Verifica si lo datos son correctos y si el coche esta libre o si pretendes conducir dos coches a la vez.';
end if;
end;
```

In the table  conducen i have this content;

(bcastrof, 9674-GZF, 2017-11-24, 2017-11-24 19:03:00.000000, 2017-11-24 22:03:00.000000)

but if intented update this row, using this sentence;

```
update conducen 
set HORARECOGIDA='2017-11-24 20:03:00.000000', HORAENTREGA='2017-11-24 22:03:00.000000'
WHERE FECHARECOGIDA='2017-11-24' 
AND USERWIN = 'bcastrof' 
and matricula = '9674-GZF'
and HORARECOGIDA = '2017-11-24 19:03:00.000000';
```

It doesn't work because it skips the exception 45002 the trigger. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

solution the problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER controlHoras1 AFTER
UPDATE ON conducen
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow for each row
BEGIN Atomic
declare entrega timestamp;
declare hoy date;
declare horaUsuario timestamp;
declare horaActual timestamp;

set (entrega)= (select max(horaentrega) from conducen where matricula = newrow.matricula and FECHARECOGIDA = newrow.fecharecogida and horaentrega!=newrow.horaentrega);
set (hoy)= (today);
set (horaUsuario)=(select max(horaentrega) from conducen where FECHARECOGIDA = newrow.fecharecogida and userwin =newrow.userwin and horaentrega!=newrow.horaentrega and horarecogida<newrow.horarecogida);
set (horaActual) = (sysdate);
if(newrow.horaRecogida < entrega) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'El coche esta ocupado a la hora que lo pretendes recoger, elige otra hora u otro coche.';
end if;
if(newrow.fecharecogida<hoy or newrow.HORARECOGIDA<horaActual) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fecha o hora de recogida menor que la fecha actual.';
end if;
if(newrow.horaRecogida<horaUsuario) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No puedes conducir dos coches a la vez.';
end if;
end;
```